# Pass list of values from a SOQL list to a custom label

Tags: apex

I have the following list

```
List\<object\> statusCheck = \[SELECT Sample_Name__c,status__c FROM object\];
```

I want to pass all values from a column in the query to a custom label with {0} using this:

```
string.format(Label.label_name, new List\<object\>{});
```

I tried a few options but without success.

Thanks,
Barry

Answer (score 0):

If you have a defined Label, you could achieve this by

```
String labelName = Label.YOURLABEL;

List<sObject> statusCheck = [SELECT Sample_Name__c, status__c FROM YourObject];

List<String> statusValues = new List<String>();
for (sObject record : statusCheck) {
    statusValues.add(String.valueOf(record.get('status__c')));
}

String formattedLabel = String.format(labelName, new List<Object>{String.join(statusValues, ', ')});
```